# Newlines removed in POST request body? (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, newline

I am building a REST API on Google App Engine (not using Endpoints) that will allow users to upload a CSV or tab-delimited file and search for potential duplicates. Since it's an API, I cannot use `<form>`s or the BlobStore's `upload_url`. I also cannot rely on having a single web client that will call this API. Instead, ideally, users will send the file in the `body` of the request.

My problem is, when I try to read the content of a tab-delimited file, I find that all newline characters have been removed, so there is no way of splitting the content into rows.

If I check the content of the file directly on the Python interpreter, I see that tabs and newlines are there (output is truncated in the example)

```
>>> with open('./data/occ_sample.txt') as o:
...     o.read()
... 
'id\ttype\tmodified\tlanguage\trights\n123456\tPhysicalObject\t2015-11-11 11:50:59.0\ten\thttp://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0\n...'
```

The `RequestHandler` logs the content of the request body:

```
import logging
class ReportApi(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info(self.request.body)
        ...
```

So when I call the API running in the `dev_appserver` via `curl`

```
curl -X POST -d @data/occ_sample.txt http://localhost:8080/api/v0/report
```

This shows up in the logs:

```
id  type    modified    language    rights123456    PhysicalObject  2015-11-11 11:50:59.0   en  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0
```

As you can see, there is nothing between the last value of the headers and the first record (`rights` and `123456` respectively) and the same happens with the last value of each record and the first one of the next.

Am I missing something obvious here? I have tried loading the data with `self.request.body`, `self.request.body_file` and `self.request.POST`, and none seem to work. I also tried applying the `Content-Type` values `text/csv`, `text/plain`, `application/csv` in the request headers, with no success. Should I add a different `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong `curl` command-line option to send your file data, and it is *this option* that is stripping the newlines.

The `-d` option *parses out your data* and sends a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and it **strips newlines**. From the [`curl` manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> `-d, --data <data>`
>
> *[...]*
>
> If you start the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or `-` if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named `'foobar'` would thus be done with `--data @foobar`. When `--data` is told to read from a file like that, **carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Use the `--data-binary` option instead:

> `--data-binary <data>`
>
> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.
>
> If you start the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a filename. Data is posted in a similar manner as `--data-ascii` does, **except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and conversions are never done.**

You *may* want to include a `Content-Type` header in that case; of course this depends on your handler if you care about that header.